# the following code is no function to set widget Visible in another activity

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, preferences

i had do some coding that to make button Visible in another activity but it still do nothing, I had three class:
`menu.class`, `levelone.class`, `leveltwo.class`
this is the following data in `menu.xml`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/f1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/f2lock"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/levellocked" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/f2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button2"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

and then the code in `menu.class`

```
        f1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.f1);      
        f1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v){
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent ();
        intent.setClassName ("com.example.application", "com.example.application.levelone");
        startActivityForResult (intent, 0);              
            }             
      });   
}
    public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    f2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f2);
    f2.setEnabled(false);
    f2lock=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.f2lock);

        switch (resultCode) {
        case 11: f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);               
                            }                   

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean levelTwoUnlocked = preferences.getBoolean("f2", false);

    if(levelTwoUnlocked){
        f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
        f2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        f2lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } 


    f2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent ();
        intent.setClassName ("com.example.application", "com.example.application.leveltwo");
        startActivityForResult (intent, 0);              
            }             
      });       
}
```

in `levelone.class` i had put

```
public void onClick(View v){
                  setResult (11);
                  finish();          
              }
           });
```

the result will send to `menu.class` to make the button visible and open `leveltwo.class`

```
            switch (resultCode) {
            case 11: f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);               
                                }
```

but nothing is happen in `menu.class` and the f2 button still Invisible

Did my code is no function or the preferences code is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed in your onActivityResult() function you have set visibility first and then initialized those variables wrt the layout try this

```
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, intent);    

    //First initialize these variables and then use setVisbility function
    f2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f2);
    f2.setEnabled(false);
    f2lock=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.f2lock);

    switch (resultCode) {
        case 11: f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);               
                        }    
    //Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: still invisible bro, did my preferences code are wrong or something code in there still wrong?

Comment: if your f2 button is still invisible that means the value you get from preferences is always false , are you updating preferences somewhere else to make it true ?

Comment: oh i forgot about that, thanks bro now the button is visible

Comment: but when i re-open the application the button back to invisible